# undefined reference to `yylex' && undefined reference to `yyin'

Tags: c++, makefile, bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to use flex and bison to create a compiler. But i receive errors when i try to compile. 
Here is the errors:

```
flex --header-file=lex.h --outfile=lex.cc lex.ll
g++ -w -Wall -Wextra -ansi -g -c -o lex.o lex.cc -lm -ll
bison -v --output-file=parse.cc --defines=parse.hh --warnings=all --feature=all parse.yy
g++ -w -Wall -Wextra -ansi -g   -c -o parse.o parse.cc
g++ -w -Wall -Wextra -ansi -g   -c -o main.o main.cc
g++ -w -Wall -Wextra -ansi -g -fkeep-inline-functions -o LFIO lex.o parse.o function.o main.o  -lfl -lm -ll
parse.o: In function `yyparse()':
/root/LFIO-combine/parse.cc:1199: undefined reference to `yylex'
main.o: In function `main':
/root/LFIO-combine/main.cc:21: undefined reference to `yyin'
/root/LFIO-combine/main.cc:21: undefined reference to `yyin'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [LFIO] Error 1
```

Here is my makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS = -w -Wall -Wextra -ansi -g
OBJECTS = lex.o parse.o function.o main.o


LFIO : $(OBJECTS)
        g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -fkeep-inline-functions -o LFIO $(OBJECTS) -lfl -lm -ll

clean :
        rm -f *.o

lex.cc : lex.ll
        flex --header-file=lex.h --outfile=lex.cc lex.ll

parse.hh : parse.cc

parse.cc : parse.yy function.h algorithm.h
        bison -v --output-file=parse.cc --defines=parse.hh --warnings=all --feature=all parse.yy

%.o: %.cc %.h
        g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< -lm -ll

main.o : main.cc lex.h parse.hh function.h algorithm.h

function.o : function.h function.cc

parse.o : parse.cc parse.hh function.h algorithm.h

lex.o :lex.h algorithm.h function.h
```

Here is my lex.ll

```
%option c++
%option ecs
%option nodefault
%option stack
%option warn
%option yylineno

%{
#include "function.h"
#include "parse.hh"
#include <limits.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int yyFlexLexer::yywrap() { return 1; }
%}

ATOM    [A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_']*
VARIABLE        [a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_']*

%%
[ \t\n]         ;
{VARIABLE} {  return (TOK_VARIABLE);}
{ATOM} {  return (TOK_ATOM);}
":-" {}
","  {}
"."  {}
<<EOF>>  {yyterminate();}
%%
```

parse.yy is like this:

```
%defines
%define api.token.prefix {TOK_}

%{
#include "function.h"
#include "lex.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef MS_WINDOWS
#include <malloc.h>
#define alloca_alloca
#endif
void yyerror(const char *s)
{
   fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);
}
extern "C" int yylex(void);

%}

%union{
......
}

%type ......


%%
......
```

And then main.cc is like this:

```
#include "function.h"
#include "algorithm.h"
#include "parse.hh"
#include "lex.h"
extern "C" int yylex(void);
extern FILE *yyin;
extern FILE *yyout;
extern int fopen();
extern int yyparse(void *);

int main(int argc, char **argv){

if(argc > 1){
if(!(yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r"))) {
perror(argv[1]);
return (1);
}
}
//yylex();
yyparse();
......
return 0;
}
```

Does anybody know what cause these errors and how to solve them?
I would be thankful if someone could make time to check these errors.

Comment: Please show the *full* output of `make`, so we can see if it tries to build and link with `lex.o`.

Comment: I have updated the output of 'make'.

Comment: Just a hunch... You're compiling the lexer as C++, but still have `extern "C" int yylex(void);`. Try to remove the `extern "C"` part.

Comment: That's the correct answer.

Comment: I'm less sure about the problem with `yyin` though... It was to long since I use Flex last. but it could be some similar issue. Try looking at the generated code, both the source and the header file to see what it says about `yyin`.

Comment: `yyin` can be found in `lex.cc`. Here is the code : `YY_DECL
{...if ( !(yy_init) )
  {...if ( ! yyin )
   yyin = & std::cin;}...}` and `int yyFlexLexer::LexerInput( char* buf, int /* max_size */ ){
 if ( yyin->eof() || yyin->fail() )
  return 0;yyin->get( buf[0] );

 if ( yyin->eof() )
  return 0;

 if ( yyin->bad() )
  return -1;

 return 1;}`

Comment: Two things: First is that the variable must be *defined* somewhere, there must be a variable definition somewhere of it. If it's not in `lex.cc` then you have to do it in some file (the declaration section in `lex.ll` perhaps?). The second thing is that `yyin` is *not* a `FILE *`. See that `yyin = &std::cin` there? That means that `yyin` should be a pointer to a `std::istream`, i.e. defined and declared as `std::istream* yyin`.

Comment: I use `grep -r "yyin" ./` to find `yyin`.but `yyin` can only be found in `lex.cc` and there is no definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Collecting my comments into an answer.</sub>

There are two problems:

The first is that the code is compiled as C++, which means the definition of `yylex` will *also* be compiled as C++. That means it is not `extern "C"`. To fix this problem remove the `extern "C"` from all declarations.

The second problem is two-fold: The first is that the symbol `yyin` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere, so you need to do it yourself. The second thing is that it should be a pointer to an `std::istream` object, and not a `FILE *`.

To solve the second problem, with `yyin`, I recommend you add the definition to your lexer declaration block:

```
%{
// Your includes...
int yyFlexLexer::yywrap() { return 1; }

// Add definition of yyin
std::istream* yyin;
%}
```

Then update the `extern` declaration in your `main.cc` file to match the definition.

Comment: Thanks. There is no `yyin` and `yylex` errors now. But by adding `std::istream* yyin;` There is new error like this `main.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cc:23:11: error: cannot convert ‘FILE* {aka _IO_FILE*}’ to ‘std::istream* {aka std::basic_istream<char>*}’ in assignment
 if(!(yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r"))) {
           ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1`

Comment: @XuWang You must of course create a normal [C++ input file stream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) and make `yyin` point to that.

Comment: OK, I will try to create this.